# oil change in Toyota Corolla 2011

Tags: oil-change, corolla

I have a Corolla 2011 LE, I want to Change oil, but I don't know which type of Oil is useful I meant(5W-20, 5W-30 ......), my car's miles is above 120 miles and for winter and summer which type is perfect to choose?
the temperature in summer up to 45c nearly but I'm not using it all day but in winter I use it nearly every day because I go to University.

please help me to choose the correct type for it.

Comment: Been a "hot" topic : https://priuschat.com/threads/why-would-you-run-0w-20-in-a-desert-hot-climate-yet-another-oil-thread.152645/

Comment: Check the cars manual for the correct one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0W-20 is the recommendation from Toyota. Right in your owner's manual. 5W-20 if 0W-20 isn't available

Answer (score 0):

You don't give any clue about the engine detail, but 5W-30 should be fine.

You should find it noted in the car's handbook and most stores will have a list where you can check make, model, year and engine type and will tell you oil specification, oil filter, etc.